# Tableau Public can't create two joins?

Tags: tableau-api

In Tableau Public, the data source sheet will not accept two joins.   When I drag the second join it wont accept

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 1):

No you can still perform joins.

1. double click on the first table, a table will open with the first data
2. Now again join your second data with the first data inside that table then automatically joins will happen
3. Now you can close that table, a join icon will be shown in your first data

Hope you got the answer :)